# Application still remains in the System Tray even after uninstalling it

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

Once I start my application, the application icon comes and sits in the system tray.
Keeping application open, I tried to uninstall the application. the application folder gets uninstalled but the icon in the system tray remains and still application runs.

p.s. I use the setup wizard to create the installer.

Comment: What technology are you using to uninstall the application? Does it make any attempt to stop the application? The system tray (aka task notification area) has a bug where it is not always updated. Does clicking/hovering the icon after uninstall make a difference?

Comment: I am using .net 4.0, c# win forms.yes i know that sometimes it the icon goes only after hovering it but my application has 4 options as a menu, on clicking right the icon in the system tray of my application, the menu strip shows up and all the options in it i am able to operate, till i click exit in the strip menu of mine the icon doesn't go and only then it seems to uninstalled(but this shouldn't happen it should automatically uninstall from the tray)

Comment: Why should it? C#/.NET 4 is what the application uses, but the installer is separate. Are you using an MSI to install/uninstall the application, if so, how is it built? Something in the installer must be manually set up to stop your application before it is uninstalled.

Comment: The uninstaller will see that it cannot delete the executables of your app.  And marks them to be deleted on the next reboot.  If that's not good enough then you'll need a custom install step that forces the program to exit.  Preferably in a nice way so that the tray icon doesn't get orphaned.

Comment: Yes I am using msi package to install and uninstall, the setup is a part of project and i build it from the code and then setup the application(Release/Debug). I checked the installer but i couldn't find any manual setup. Check the registry settings also from the setup, nothing is happening @ gt

Comment: Is this the default behavior of an installer?or is there anything that should be done manually? should the user only should provide the option to uninstall? @Hans Passant

Comment: I can still don't find the solution for this as to how can it be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the only way to remove notify icon from tray area was with:

```
myNotifyIcon.Visible = false;
```

This makes notify icon dissapear immediately. Even when I've stopped application completely,
without setting notifyIcon's visibility to false, it results in icon staying in tray area as long as mouse pointer wasn't hovered over it.

Try to use this command inside your uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

use [Notification Area Cleaner](http://www.itsamples.com/notification-area-cleaner.html) application. fix everything without problems in windows 8.1

version: 1.0 (32-bit)  [download](http://www.itsamples.com/downloads/notification-area-cleaner.zip)   (50KB, revised March 07, 2010)

version: 1.0 (64-bit)  [download](http://www.itsamples.com/downloads/notification-area-cleaner-x64.zip)   (57KB, revised March 14, 2011)